# mFusedLocationApi.getLocation() method ALWAYS returns null

Tags: android

Ok this is code taken from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-place-tutorial. My problem is:  fusedLocationApi.getLocation() method ALWAYS returns null. I've seen many related articles on stackOverflow as well as other sites. I've been searching high and low and I just don't understand why this happens or can find solution to resolve this.

```
package com.example.Example;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;
    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    }





    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        getLocationPermission();
        updateLocationUI();
        getDeviceLocation();
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation() {
    /*
     * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
     * cases when a location is not available.
     */
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            mLastKnownLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                            if(mLastKnownLocation!= null){
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                //Place a maker here
                              //  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Habit events").position());
                              //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Marker is added to the map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch(SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }


    private void getLocationPermission() {
    /*
     * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
     * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
     * onRequestPermissionsResult.
     */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }


    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                mLastKnownLocation = null;
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```